# how to list or download BIOS logs from HPilo CLI DL380p

Tags: bios, hp, lilo

I looked around a lot but could not find any commands to display following HP logs from CLI

- iLO Event Log
- Integrated Management Log
- Active Health Log

I was also not able to display / list system health from ilo prompt. whats up with the HP folks???? By the way this is DL380p, and it is ilo v4.0

I intend to list all entries in log: like this: (the way it shows in CSV output from web)

```
685     01/16/2021 19:59    01/16/2021 19:59    1   Browser login: <uid> - <IP_addr>(DNS name not found).
684     01/16/2021 19:53    01/16/2021 19:53    1   SSH login: <uid> - <IP_Addr>(DNS name not found).
```

...

following does not work...

```
</>hpiLO-> show ilo log all

status=2
status_tag=COMMAND PROCESSING FAILED
error_tag=INVALID OPTION
Fri Jan 15 21:38:57 2021
```

this does not work....

```
</>hpiLO-> show /system1/log1

status=0
status_tag=COMMAND COMPLETED
Sat Jan 16 19:54:14 2021



/system1/log1
  Targets
    record1
    record2
    record3
    record4
    record5
    record6
    record7
    record8
    record9
    record10
    record11
    record12
    record13
    record14
    record15
    record16
    record17
    record18
    record19
    record20
    record21
    record22
    record23
    record24
    record25
    record26
  Properties
  Verbs
    cd version exit show delete


</>hpiLO-> show /map1/log1

status=0
status_tag=COMMAND COMPLETED
Sat Jan 16 19:54:34 2021



/map1/log1
  Targets
    record1
    record2
    record3
    record4
    record5
    record6
    record7
    record8
    record9
    record10
    record11
    record12
    record13
    record14
    record15
    record16
    record17
    record18
    record19
    record20
    record21
    record22
    record23
    record24
    record25
    record26
    record27
    record28
    record29
    record30
    record31
    record32
    record33
    record34
    record35
    record36
    record37
    record38
    record39
    record40
    record41
    record42
    record43
    record44
    record45
    record46
    record47
    record48
    record49
    record50
    record51
    record52
    record53
    record54
    record55
    record56
    record57
    record58
    record59
    record60
    record61
    record62
    record63
    record64
    record65
    record66
    record67
    record68
    record69
    record70
    record71
    record72
    record73
    record74
    record75
    record76
    record77
    record78
    record79
    record80
    record81
    record82
    record83
    record84
    record85
    record86
    record87
    record88
    record89
    record90
    record91
    record92
    record93
    record94
    record95
    record96
    record97
    record98
    record99
    record100
    record101
    record102
    record103
    record104
    record105
    record106
    record107
    record108
    record109
    record110
    record111
    record112
    record113
    record114
    record115
    record116
    record117
    record118
    record119
    record120
    record121
    record122
    record123
    record124
    record125
    record126
    record127
    record128
    record129
    record130
    record131
    record132
    record133
    record134
    record135
    record136
    record137
    record138
    record139
    record140
    record141
    record142
    record143
    record144
    record145
    record146
    record147
    record148
    record149
    record150
    record151
    record152
    record153
    record154
    record155
    record156
    record157
    record158
    record159
    record160
    record161
    record162
    record163
    record164
    record165
    record166
    record167
    record168
    record169
    record170
    record171
    record172
    record173
    record174
    record175
    record176
    record177
    record178
    record179
    record180
    record181
    record182
    record183
    record184
    record185
    record186
    record187
    record188
    record189
    record190
    record191
    record192
    record193
    record194
    record195
    record196
    record197
    record198
    record199
    record200
    record201
    record202
    record203
    record204
    record205
    record206
    record207
    record208
    record209
    record210
    record211
    record212
    record213
    record214
    record215
    record216
    record217
    record218
    record219
    record220
    record221
    record222
    record223
    record224
    record225
    record226
    record227
    record228
    record229
    record230
    record231
    record232
    record233
    record234
    record235
    record236
    record237
    record238
    record239
    record240
    record241
    record242
    record243
    record244
    record245
    record246
    record247
    record248
    record249
    record250
    record251
    record252
    record253
    record254
    record255
    record256
    record257
    record258
    record259
    record260
    record261
    record262
    record263
    record264
    record265
    record266
    record267
    record268
    record269
    record270
    record271
    record272
    record273
    record274
    record275
    record276
    record277
  Properties
  Verbs
    cd version exit show delete


</>hpiLO->
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Linux/Unix? It sounds more like a serverfault.com question to me.

Comment: Oskar, you are right. it didnt occur to me when i posted the quest. can we move the question there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not Unix/Linux related (maybe very remotely, as HP iLO is internally Linux based, and sometimes HP support when troubleshooting issues can give you a special iLO build that allows access to actual Linux shell :) - I have once used such one), but I'll answer it anyway :)

The command you typed is completely wrong. Let's start with typing just `show`. You'll get the following (there's more, that's the important part of the output):

```
/
  Targets
    system1
    map1
```

So argument to `show` command can start with either `/system1` or `/map1`. Type `show /system1` and see what are the further possibilities.

In short, the command for Integrated Management Log is:

```
show /system1/log1
```

This will give you a list of all log entries, from `record1` to - let's say - `record200`. To view a particular log entry, type:

```
show /system1/log1/record153
```

Well, not most user-friendly, but that's how it works. You can also display all log entries at once (but that's a lot of output!) using the command:

```
show -a /system1/log1
```

For the iLO Event Log, do the same but use `/map1/log1` instead of `/system1/log1`.

I'm not aware of a possibility to access Active Health Log from the CLI.

Comment: thanks for the response. i had tried all that already. it just return the recordXX s  there must be some undocumented switch etc. pl see updated question detail.

Comment: It had always worked on any server with iLO I have used, and I used many of them. You must be doing something wrong. What does exactly the command like `show /system1/log1/record1` output on your server?

Comment: i updated question to clarify. i already know individual record can be displayed like that.

Comment: Try this: `show -a /system1/log1`. This will output the entire log, but not in the format you want. However, there's no other possibility.

Comment: thx that owrked. i dont know if i missed that anywhere in documentation. Also following works for AHS log:   To download the entire Active Health System Log:
   curl "https://<iLO_IP_address>/ahsdata/ahs.ahs?downloadAll=1" -k -v -u <username>:<password> -o <filename>.ahs

Comment: I just checked the documentation before I wrote my previous comment. It is mentioned in the documentation that option `-a` exists, but it's not said clearly what does it do, so I just tried it :)